# Php for loop with 2 variables?

Tags: php, for-loop, infinite-loop

is it possible to do this? (here is my code)

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++){
  for ($j = 10 ; $j >= 0 ; $j--){
     echo "Var " . $i . " is " . $k . "<br>";
  }
}
```

I want something like this:

var 0 is 10

var 1 is 9

var 2 is 8 ...

But my code is wrong, it gives a huge list. Php guru, help me !!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i=0, $k=10; $i<=10 ; $i++, $k--) {
    echo "Var " . $i . " is " . $k . "<br>";
}
```

The two variables `$i` and `$k` are initialized with `0` and `10` respectively. At the end of each each loop `$i` will be incremented by one (`$i++`) and `$k` decremented by one (`$k--`). So `$i` will have the values 0, 1, …, 10 and `$k` the values 10, 9, …, 0.

Comment: Oh wow. I had no idea you set multiple vars within a for-loop. Nice.

Comment: My next question: can you do this in C, C++, Java, and C#?

Comment: @Thomas, yes.  C++ and C# definitely, and I'm pretty sure about C and Java, but I try to avoid it as it can get unreadable fast.

Comment: There are only rare occasions where I would want to use it, but I'm totally putting this one in my toolbelt.

Comment: Thanks for this code snippet. Didn't think that you could do something like this...

Answer (score 4):

You could also add a condition for the second variable

```
for ($i=0, $k=10; $i<=10, $k>=0 ; $i++, $k--) {
    echo "Var " . $i . " is " . $k . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using two for-loops for what you'd like to achieve as you're looping 121 times total (11x11). What you really want is just to have a counter declared outside of the loop that tracks j, and then decrement j inside the loop.

Edit: Thanks Gumbo for catching the inclusion for me.

Comment: In fact it’s 11·11=121 (from 0 to 10 inclusive).

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't even see that.

Answer (score 1):

If, as your code looks like, you have two values running the opposite direction you could simply substract:

```
echo "Var " . $i . " is " . 10 - $i . "<br>";
```

But I guess that's not really what you want? Also, be careful with the suggested [comma operator](http://php.mirror.camelnetwork.com/manual/en/language.expressions.php#90327). While it is a nice thing it can cause naughty side effects in other languages like [C and C++](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html) as PHP implements it differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_map(function($i) {
    echo "Var {$i} is ".(10-$i)."<br/>".PHP_EOL; 
}, range(1,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other (correct) answers, what you were doing is called *nesting* loops.  This means that for every iteration of the outer loop (the first one), you were completing the entire inner loop.  This means that instead of 11 outputs, you get `11 + 11 + 11 + ... = 11 * 11` outputs

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get a start and end time and store in the database, given a start and end time, you loop through each time using two variables i&j

```
   $start = "09:00";
   $end = "18:00";
   $strEnTim = strtotime("10.00");

   $slotStart = strtotime($start);
   $slotEnd = strtotime($end);
   $slotNow = $slotStart;

   for( $i=$slotStart, $j=$strEnTim; $i, $j<=$slotEnd; $i+=3600,  $j+=3600) 
   {
        if(( $i < $slotNow) && ( $j < $strEnTim)) continue;
        Slot::create([
            'start_time' => date("H:i",$i),
            'end_time' => date("H:i", $j)
        ]);
   }
```