# How to use 2 variables in For loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

My PHP code (so far not working as I want it to) -

```
for ($x=0, $y=0; $x<=163, $y<=98 ; $x++, $y++) {
    echo "Value of x = " . $x . " & y = " . $y . "<br>";
}
```

What I was trying to achieve is - it should `echo` even if one condition matches. Right now it stops when one condition is fulfilled, i.e. in this case when `y=98`, it stopped. Also there may be cases when `y>=x` in contrast to given code where `x>y`

Edit -
The [duplicate marked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172553/php-for-loop-with-2-variables) question, did not solve my problem as in that question, range of both the variables were same, so it could have been achieved by the mentioned answer (by increasing one variable). In my case both variables has different range.
Also I tried this

```
for ($x=0, $y=0; $x<=163 || $y<=98 ; $x++, $y++) {
    echo "Value of x = " . $x . " & y = " . $y . "<br>";
}
```

But it's also not helping me to achieve my desired output.

**Edit 2** -  I think I couldn't explain properly earlier, with what I wanted the output to be.
So I am trying to demonstrate by small e.g. with `x=3, y=2`

```
x=1, y=1
x=2, y=1
x=3, y=1
x=1, y=2
x=2, y=2
x=3, y=2
```

I am trying to achieve something like this. I don't know, what this ?matrix is called in maths (so it's possible my question title is wrong).

Comment: Do you understand logical operators (||/OR and &&/AND)?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, a bit, but I am unable to figure out how to should I use II operator in for loop?

Comment: $x<=163 || $y<=98 will loop you 164 times $x<=163 && $y<=98 will loop you 99, and $x<=163, $y<=98 will loop you 99

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that through a basic nested loop. Basically you loop over `y` in the outer loop and for each iteration of `y` you do a another for loop for `x`. Try this and adjust `x` and `y` as necessary.

```
<?php

for ($y=0; $y<=98 ; $y++) { 
    for ($x=0; $x<=163; $x++) {
        echo "Value of x = " . $x . " & y = " . $y . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari You have to use a nested for loop for that. I edited my answer.